# Неправильная конфигурация MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Всем привет,
столкнулся с такой проблемой что в файле конфигураций MySQL путь к файлу `mysql.sock` неправильный, вместо того чтобы обращаться к `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock` он обращаеться к `var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.
Для тестирования я создал файл где пытаюсь подключиться к БД, файл запускаю через команду `php checkConnect.php`. При подключение с порта `127.0.0.1` то всё работает, но когда пытаюсь подключться через `localhost`, через сокет, мне выдаёт ошибку `permission denied`. При запуске файла с помощь `sudo php checkConnect.php` то всё рабоатет.

На данный момент сервер работает и он хорошо так нагружен и чтобы не перезапустить MySQL, можно скопировать файл `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` в директорий `/var/run/mysql/` и 6 параметром в подключений mysql указать путь к скопированому файлу?

Пример :

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'пользователь', 'пароль', 'базаданных', 'порт', '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock');
```

Я хотел это сделать но коллеги сказать что это может сломать работу с БД.
Вот вопрос почему я всё это написал, сломаю ли я работу сервера если скопираю файл `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` в `var/run/mysql/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используемый сокет определяется значением глобальной переменной `@@GLOBAL.socket`. Переменная - только глобальная и **не динамическая**, её значение нельзя изменить в процессе работы сервера.

Единственный способ изменения этой настройки - корректировка файла конфигурации либо командной строки запуска сервиса сервера, а затем рестарт сервера.

> и чтобы не перезапустить MySQL

Невозможно.

> сломаю ли я работу сервера если скопираю файл

В этом нет никакого смысла. Даже если скопировать файл в новое местоположение, это ничего не изменит. Сервер всё равно продолжит использовать "старый" файл.

А вот если попытаться изменить или удалить файл сокета, это практически гарантированно приведёт к краху сервера.